# Use a generic class with type parameters in xmlbean

Tags: java, spring, xmlbeans

I search a solution for use with bean a generic class like this:

```
public class CompositeMapper<T extends Model, U extends Command, C extends Context> implements Mapper<T, U, C>
{ 
    protected List<Mapper<T, U, C>> mappers;

    /* ... */
}
```

I would use a bean like this:

```
<bean id="beanMapper" class="com.test.CompositeMapper">
    <property name="mappers">
        <list value-type="com.test.Mapper">
            <bean class="com.test.Mapper1"/>
            <bean class="com.test.Mapper2"/>
            <bean class="com.test.Mapper2"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Streangly, this bean works. But I can use anything that is enter in the generic case, so not specialized.

But I don't find a solution for typed my generic object `com.test.Mapper<com.test.MyModel, com.test.MyCommand, com.test.MyContext>`, it not possible in value-type. I not found other solution than to create an empty class for replace `com.test.CompositeMapper` in my bean. For example :

```
public class MyCompositeMapper extends CompositeMapper<MyModel, MyCommand, MyContext>
{
    public MyCompositeMapper()
    {
        super();
    }
}
```

But I would avoid creating this class, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

No, `value-type` is used for type conversion so note that if `com.test.Mapper.class.isAssingnableFrom(com.test.Mapper1.class)` returns `true`, it will be accepted.

However, you could use Java Configuration classes to enforce the generic type checks.